# Flow chart designer in html5

Tags: html, jquery-ui, canvas

I have a spec for a flow designer, and i am having a hard time finding the right tools to make it with,

Min spec - 
Draggable blocks, that can connect with arrows
each block shows min details, on hover the block should grow and show extra details

Needs to be in html5

I was looking at KinectJS/EaselJS to draw my flow,
But i need to have DOM elements (comboboxes/textboxes/etc) in each of the extended blocks for edit, and i can't find a decent way to do that with either of them.

I looked at JQueryUI's draggable, which is great for dragging blocks of DOM elements, but then drawing arrows between them becomes really hard.

Does anyone made something like that or can give me any direction?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your specs limit your options a bit.

You need draggable divs that contain live select and text-input elements.

**I would try this combination:**

- jQueryUI for your draggable divs.
- SVG lines for your connectors using `marker-start` and `marker-end` for arrowheads

Use SVG curves as connectors if you're ambitious ;)

**Alternative #1: D3.**

If you're willing to go through a learning curve, d3 is a very nice SVG infrastructure for flow charts (flexible data elements with connectors).  Each d3 element (=your flowchart blocks) can listen for mouse and keyboard events but d3 has no combobox or text elements -- you would have to code those yourself.  A shortcut to combobox/text input would be to use CSS position an html  select/text element over the d3 element when input was required.

**Alternative #2: KineticJS (or your other favorite canvas library)**

KineticJS gives you block elements (Rect) and connectors (polyline) out-of-the-box.  But again, input is limited.  But Kinetic elements are quite flexible.  Combining Kinetic elements with old-fashioned browser events could work too.

Here's starter code that lets KineticJS listen for user's keyboard events and display text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    // this variable holds the current text
    var typedText="";

    // create a text object
    var text = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: 20,
        y: 30,
        fontSize: 30,
        text: "",
        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
        fill: 'green'
    });
    layer.add(text);
    layer.draw();


    // listen for keys

    // get the usual "printable" keys
    $(document).on('keypress',(function(e){

        // get the key
        key=e.which;

        // let keydown handle control keys 
        if(key<32){return;}

        // add the typed character
        typedText+=String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
        text.setText(typedText);;
        layer.drawScene();
    }));


    // handle control keys like backspace
    $(document).on('keydown',(function(e){

        // get the key
        var key=event.which;

        // Let keypress handle displayable characters
        if(key>46){ return; }


        // handle the backspace 
        // (and any other control keys you want to program)
        switch(key){
              case 8: //backspace:
                if(typedText.length>0){
                    typedText=typedText.slice(0,-1);
                    text.setText(typedText);;
                    layer.drawScene();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }));


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <p>Type...(and use the backspace)!</p>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Canvas will probably be the best way to draw the arrows if they are changing all the time. You could either have a large canvas object behind your blocks, or build a different canvas element for each arrow.

When I build something similar I had a setTimeout function update specific arrows only while the mouse button was down. Just to make it look nicer.